# Use just Sharepoint 2010 foundation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointfoundation2010

am an ASP.NET developer new to Sharepoint.

Having installed Sharepoint Server 2010, SQL and VStudio on Server 2008 I'm trying find out if there is a way to disable all the extra features that come with SP Server.

I wish to develop SP foundation apps only.

Do I need to uninstall SP server and just install SP foundation or is there some other way of turning the extra stuff off?

For example, I can create Surveys but I don't want them if they're not in foundation.

Comment: You have asked 10 questions, but you have not accepted any answers. You should accept answers that help you, if you want people to continue to answer your questions

Answer (score 2):

If you really only want SP Foundation stuff on your development machine, the best way is indeed to remove SharePoint Server and install SharePoint Foundation instead.

I suppose the reason behind this is to not accidently use things that are not available in Foundation ?

btw: Surveys exist in Foundation as well ;)

Comment: Yes, the client wants to resist spending $$ on Server 2010. Can't blame them can you. Thanks very much Tom, a new VM in order I think :)

Comment: It's not that much work... just copy the existing VM (so that you also have a version with SP Server for future projects), remove SP Server from it and install SP Foundation instead. If the answer was useful, please mark it as the accepted answer. Of course you're free to wait a couple of days to see what others think about the matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can just deactivate all the server features under farm/web app/site collection/site. we've been developing on MOSS machine for WSS for years, and it works well. Just pay attention if you use any graphics that come with sharepoint, as they might be installed by the server and not WSS.