# SharePoint Foundation 2010 API. Is it the right one to use?

Tags: api, sharepoint

We are developing an application that is meant to be used by our customers to query and upload documents to their SharePoint 2010 Servers. As I understand it, I will need to use the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime` dlls (among others) and SharePoint's Managed Client Object Model API. From what I've read, I can get the API from SharePoint Foundation 2010.

But, if I'm connecting to SharePoint 2010, is the Managed Client Object Model API found in SharePoint Foundation 2010 appropriate to use? Or do I need to get the libraries/API from SharePoint 2010 (i.e. not Foundation)?

To put it another way, is the Managed Client Object Model API found in SharePoint Foundation 2010 appropriate for connecting to SharePoint 2010 Server? Or is it only good for connecting to SharePoint Foundation 2010 Server?

Answer (score 3):

Anything you can do in SharePoint Foundation 2010 can be done in SharePoint 2010 Server.  The former was extended to produce the latter. In other words, it should be ok to use the API for Foundation on the 2010 Server.  Related question: [Use just Sharepoint 2010 foundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687919/use-just-sharepoint-2010-foundation)